# Sort objects in array based on particular property value

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of objects like:-

```
myobject[
  {name:'Zeta' ,count:1},
  {name:'Nei',count:20},
  {name:'tri',count:3)

];
```

I want object with the name tri to appear as first object instead of third.
how can i do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1129270/1544886 or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: atleast do a google search before asking here

Comment: I don't know how you could achieve that since small letters are after the capital letters in the ASCII table. The 'tri' word will be always after the words that starts capital letters.If you want to use alphabetical order that your should ignore case when you do sorting of your array.

Comment: @luci you can write your own sort function and choose to ignore case. Refer to my first link above

Comment: myobject.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
});